# elasticsearch why the index is red health state, after I close the index

Tags: elasticsearch

To decrease a big ES cluster load (The ES hold data for about 3 years), I [close](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-close.html) the history index. But why the the **closed** index is RED sometimes?

Comment: Did you check if the index was RED before closing it? that would mean that at least one primary shard was not properly allocated.

Comment: you mean if closing  a GREEN  index, the closed index will never be RED?

Comment: A closed index can only become RED if you mess up with that index data on the filesystem after it has been closed. It can also happen if your index doesn't have any replicas and one node hosting one of the primary shards is unprovisioned while the index was closed. Can you tell what was the health of that index BEFORE closing it?

Comment: Before closing it, the index is GREEN. I find the https://discuss.elastic.co/t/closed-indices-do-not-release-shards/297142/2 that "Closed indices will consume disk space until deleted, and they are still properly replicated in case you lose some of the nodes in your cluster"

Comment: Which version do you have?

Comment: ES version is 7.4.1

Comment: Can you run this and update your question with the results you get: `GET _cluster/allocation/explain`